# fetching records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query like below :

```
SELECT r.RiderName,
       bm.BranchName,
       oa.AddedOn AS OrderDate,
       ra.CheckIn,
       ra.CheckOut,
       COUNT(om.OrderId) TotalOrder,
       SUM(om.OrderAmount) AS TotalAmount,
       om.OrderId
FROM RiderAttendance ra
INNER JOIN Riders r ON r.RiderId = ra.RiderId
INNER JOIN BranchMaster bm ON bm.BranchId = ra.BranchId
INNER JOIN OrderAssign oa ON oa.RiderId = ra.RiderId
INNER JOIN OrderDetail od ON od.OrderId = oa.OrderId
INNER JOIN OrderMaster om ON od.OrderId = om.OrderId
WHERE od.OrderId != 0
  AND bm.BranchId = 82
  AND oa.AddedOn >= '05/29/2018'
  AND oa.AddedOn <= '05/31/2018'
GROUP BY r.RiderName,
         bm.BranchName,
         oa.AddedOn,
         ra.CheckIn,
         ra.CheckOut,
         om.OrderId
```

Fetching results like [image].

Above you can see that sic_name_txt = 'Corporate Bonds' has 2 possible values for Percentage, 'pgperc1' and 'pgperc', with two different sic_srcid_txt 'SARA' and 'Default'

I want the row with 'Corporate Bonds' 'Percentage' 'pgperc1' to be selected and not the other

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: When asking a question for SQL, don't forget, we don't have access to your data. Also, images of data is often less than useful; we can't interact with it. Your explanation has a little to be desired as well; there's little context for us, especially when we don't have the original source data. Here's a good place to start: [Forum Etiquette: How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to the end of your code:

```
and sic_name_txt='CORPORATE BONDS' 
and chd_column_header_txt='Percentage'
and chd_column_header_text_txt='pgperc1'
```

Comment: no i want these along with the other records. Basically for each unique sic_name_txt i want unique chd_column_header_txt with the sic_srcid_txt  SARA taking preference over the rest

Comment: Share the desired output. The question is too unclear.